# Closing dynamically created threads

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

This is for an Operating Systems programming assignment. I'm attempting to read **n** number of files, use threads to search each file for a number of occurrences for a specific character.

```
./mycount j new.txt some.txt here.txt hello.txt
```

The output for my test code as is should be:

```
argumentCount: 6
threadCount: 4
pthread_create() for thread 0 returns: 0
Thread 1
pthread_create() for thread 1 returns: 0
Thread 2
pthread_create() for thread 2 returns: 0
Thread 3
pthread_create() for thread 3 returns: 0
Thread 4
```

However each execution of **mycount** is different, with the last thread usually not executing/printing. Either that or they'll print sporadically, in tandem, etc.

I'm attempting to utilize a mutex to ensure the integrity of my data but I'm not sure what's really happening behind the scenes.

How do I ensure that everything finishes the same way each time? The last thread always returns 0, but it sometimes won't execute the function I give it completely.

Code:

```
//GLOBALS
int occurrences = 0;

//PROTOTYPES
void *scanFile( void *filePtr );

//Initialize space for mutex.
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

//Receive arguments from .exe call
void main ( int argumentCount, char *argumentVariables[] )
{
    //Exit if argumentCount is > 50.
    if (argumentCount > 50)
    {
        perror("Too many arguments. Enter less than 50.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("argumentCount: %d \n", argumentCount);
    //Instantiate variables.
    //i - iterator
    //*newCommand - Used to hold string value of first command entered.
    //*newVector - Used to hold string of the rest of the commands. Is a vector.
    int i;
    char *searchCharacter;
    char *newVector[argumentCount];

    //Iterate through command line arguments and split them.
    for (i = 0; i < argumentCount; i++)
    {
        searchCharacter = argumentVariables[1];
        if (i < argumentCount - 1)
        {
            newVector[i] = argumentVariables[1 + i];
        }
        else
        {
            newVector[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    //Exit if newest command is NULL.
    if (searchCharacter == NULL)
    {
        perror("No character entered!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int threads = argumentCount - 2;
    printf("threadCount: %d \n", threads);
    pthread_t * thread = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t)*threads);

    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
    {
        int ret;
        char *message = "Thread";
        ret = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, scanFile, (void*) message);
        if (ret != 0)
        {
            printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n", ret);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("pthread_create() for thread %d returns: %d\n", i, ret);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void *scanFile( void *filePtr )
{
    pthread_mutex_lock( &mutex );
    char *message;
    message = (char *) filePtr;
    occurrences += 1;
    printf("%s %d\n", message, occurrences);
    pthread_mutex_unlock( &mutex );
}
```

Comment: Where is the code that *joins* the threads? Why is this important to ensure that "all threads to start and complete work"?

Comment: I'm not sure how to join **n** threads. Also, it's important for me to ensure they all execute because in the future I will need each thread to scan a file for a number of occurrences of a specific character.

Comment: See ["pthread join" (web)](https://www.google.com/search?q=pthread+join) and ["pthread join" (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pthread+join).

Comment: @AustinHeath, joining n threads is just joining one at a time. What is happening is that your process is exiting before all of the threads complete, because you're not doing anything to prevent that. As soon as you've started them, you're terminating the process (and all its threads).

Comment: Did it! Thanks! Posting solution. @KenThomases

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to user2864740 and Ken Thomases.

Added:

```
for (int j = 0; j < threads; j++)
{
    //Join the threads so all the data is good to go.
    pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
}
```

Correction:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++)
{
    request[i].file = argumentVariables[i + 2];
    request[i].character = searchCharacter;

    //Create the thread. Any output from the integer newThread is an error code.
    newThread = pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, *scanFile, &request[i]);
    if (newThread != 0)
    {
        printf("Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n", newThread);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

for (int j = 0; j < threads; j++)
{
    //Join the threads so all the data is good to go.
    pthread_join(thread[j], NULL);
}
```

Comment: Well, this solves the problem but eliminates any concurrency. That is, you're no longer getting any benefits from using multiple threads. You're creating one at a time and waiting for that one to finish before launching the next. You should create them all before joining any of them.

Comment: @KenThomases Figured it out! Works like expected now.